# Can I use a constant voltage and constant current LED driver to charge a battery?

Tags: battery-charging, led-driver

I can charge a battery with a bench power supply by setting desired voltage and current. Is it possible to use, for example, [this](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=HLG-320H) LED driver in the same way? I just want something cheaper, more powerful and more convenient than a power supply to charge my lithium battery.

Answer (score 2):

While nothing prevents you from charging lithium batteries with bench top supply, you really should not. It will not automatically turn off when charging current has dropped low enough to end the charging cycle.

Same applies to the constant current power supply. It will push constant current into battery until battery voltage rises high enough so the supply can't output constant current any more. But at this point the voltage will be the max output voltage, e.g. 12V, which will be way too much for a 1S or 2S pack. And the constant current is huge, much more than what typical cells accept. And the power supply definitely does not support balancing.

So while you can, there is just so many things that can go wrong, damage the battery and it might explode or burst into flames and cause damage to property and injurt to people.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get dedicated device with all the necessary tools and protections?

Battery chargers have various modes such as trickle charge for deeply discharged batteries (for example, charging at 1/10 of normal rate until the battery is no longer considered deeply discharged).

You have also little to no control over what happens when battery voltage reaches your supply's max output voltage. The chargers keep supplying smaller and smaller current with fixed voltage until charging current is so small that the charger stops the process and calls it charged. Do you know what your supply will do when it can't force enough current due to too small voltage difference between battery and your supply?

Besides, your LED supply seems to not actually match battery voltage. For example, 12V battery has over 13V when it's fully charged. So you can't use 12V supply because it won't charge the battery for more than a half or so, while 15V supply will do boom (or some other kind of mishap you don't want to know anyway).

Dedicated chargers are designed around batteries and take into account their properties and needs, while your supply is pretty much a constant current source, which is only one of multiple charger modes. LED supply can be a temporary makeshift solution if you don't have a charger at hand and waiting for its delivery, but it requires supervision. And it is by no means permanent solution. Better use lab power supply until proper charger arrives.